# Use Apple Pay from a separate Swift Framework/Module

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, applepay, entitlements

I would like to create a framework that possesses the capability to bill via Apple Pay. In a normal app that would involve me creating a merchant and setting up Apple Pay capability in an iOS app. However, I am not targeting an iOS App, but I am targeting a Swift Framework!

The project that will use my Swift Framework, ironically, already has Apple Pay capability and its own merchant and entitlements. But during a certain scenario of app execution, I need to present my own Apple Pay billing screen for my own merchant, and I have to do this from my non-main module, non-main bundle, from a framework.

The question is: how can I configure Apple Pay for my framework in a way that allows 2 merchants in a same app to be able to bill?

Alternatively: what if I ask the App that will be integrating my SDK to add my `merchantId` to its Apple Pay entitlements so that I use this `merchantId` to create `PKPaymentRequest`s?

Comment: I don't believe that you can do this. The ApplePay entitlement is linked to the developer. An app from another developer that is using your framework can't include an entitlement to a merchant configuration in your developer account.

Comment: Hm, great point, but what if I ask the App that uses the SDK to add my merchant ID to its own Apple Pay configuration so that I use the same Apple Pay merchant ID to create PKPaymentRequest?

Comment: I don't see how you could do that; They would need to generate a public/private key pair and share that with you, and I don't think you can have multiple merchant IDs in an app

Comment: @Paulw11 no no no we aren't gonna use THEIR merchant id, we gonna let them use our merchant id though. The merchantId's are linked to the public keys of the certificates, I wonder if the Xcode will let them download the keys during the compilation process or something...

Comment: They can't use your merchant id because your merchant id won't be in their Apple developer account https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/setting_up_apple_pay . Even if they did use your merchant id, all of the payments they took in their app would go to you.  I think you need to rethink your approach. You can't provide a framework for others that will result in payments being made to you.

Comment: Nah nah, that's the point - it's an adjacent billing flow, which is supposed to be supplementary to Apple Pay that they have already plugged in. I wonder if one really can't use a merchantId from a different Apple Development Team? Do you happen to know of any concrete proof, a particular line in the docs that unambiguously prohibits this?

Comment: Not in the documentation, but it is implied.  And when you create the capability in Xcode it needs to match (or create) a merchant ID from your developer account to put into the provisioning profile, so I don't see how you could use a merchant id that isn't in your developer account.

Comment: Once I test this via code, I will surely notify you of the results and thank you very much for your participation.

Comment: @Paulw11 you ended up being absolutely correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure Apple Pay for my framework in a way that allows 2 merchants in a same app to be able to bill?

That's very easy, the merchantId just has to be in their entitlements, and they should pass it into the framework.

> What if I ask the App that uses the SDK to add my merchant ID to its own Apple Pay configuration so that I use the same Apple Pay merchant ID to create PKPaymentRequest?

Their code will not compile because the merchantId in the entitlements **must** come from their own developer account.

What is the correct way to do in your scenario is:

- ask them to create a merchantId for their account
- ask them to create the certificates and pass them onto you
- configure the certificates as your own with your acquiring system
- make sure you use this merchantId while making payments in the integrated SDK

Comment: Different Users are creating their own app and using my framework in it. In which i have integrated Apple pay. So, Is it possible that by passing different merchantIDs in our SDK I can successfully get payment in My merchant using Apple pay?

Comment: @DivyaThakkar Nope - it will be their merchant ID so they get the money. They can't use your Merchant ID